# angular 1.6.7 simple select binding not setting the select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', [function() {
      this.model = {
        person: {
          titleId: 4
        }
      }
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as nb">
    <select ng-model="nb.model.person.titleId">
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
          <option value="4">D</option>
      </select>
      
      <p>{{nb.model.person.titleId}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I select `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` the model value is updated as expected. `person` has a `titleId` value between 1 and 4.

However when loading up a new model, with a `titleId`.

```
{
    "person": {
        "titleId": 4
    }
}
```

The select is not being set to the correct value. The model binding seems to be working 1 way, and not 2 way?

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set it as `"4"`

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', [function() {
      this.model = {
        person: {
          titleId: "4"
        }
      }
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as nb">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="Person_TitleId" name="Person.TitleId" ng-model="nb.model.person.titleId">
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
          <option value="4">D</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

However I would recommend you to use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', [function() {
      this.model = {
        person: {
          titleId: 4
        }
      }
      this.options = [{
        label: 'A',
        titleId: 1
      }, {
        label: 'B',
        titleId: 2
      }, {
        label: 'C',
        titleId: 3
      }, {
        label: 'D',
        titleId: 4
      }]

    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as nb">
    <select ng-model="nb.model.person" ng-options="a.label for a in nb.options track by a.titleId ">          
      </select>
    <p>{{nb.model.person}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response: that's decidedly inconvenient when the value is in fact a number.

Comment: @Jim, then better use `ngOptions` I have updated answer and added code snippet above with it